# prove $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $f(x)$ isn't

Tags: general-topology, continuity

f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin(1/x)& x\neq0\\ x=0&x=0\end{cases} and g(x)=\begin{cases} x\sin(1/x)& x\neq0\\ x=0&x=0\end{cases} Prove g(x) is continuous at x=0 and f(x) isn't.

Is this sufficient?

To prove g(x) is continuous take a sequence $x_n $. if $ x_n \rightarrow 0$ then $x\sin(1/x) \rightarrow 0 $ so g(x) is continuous at 0.

Assume f(x) is continuous at 0. if $ x_n \rightarrow 0$ then $\sin(1/x) \rightarrow0 $. Since $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(1/x)$ is undefined, f(x) is not convergent, so f(x) is not continuous

Comment: Sketching a graph of each of these should suggest how to proceed in both cases

Answer (score 1):

For $g(x)$, your argument is fine (though it should be more rigorous; argue *why* the limit of $f(x_n)\to0$ as $n\to0$).

For the function $f(x)$, you should exhibit two explicit sequences showing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(1/x)$ is not defined (therby showing $\lim f(x_n)\neq0$ anyway).

Answer (score 0):

To show $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, we need to come up with a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to 0 such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(0)=0$.

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then, $x_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, but $f(x_n)=\sin(n)$ which does not converge as $n\to \infty$.

You can argue continuity of $g$ using the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, if $|x|<\delta=\epsilon$, then $|g(x)|\leq |x|<\epsilon.$

Comment: this may seem stupid but you say $f(x_n)=\sin(n)$ because $f(x_n)=\sin(1/x_n)=\sin(1/(1/n))$ ?

Comment: Yes, $1/(1/n)=n$

Answer (score 0):

1. Let us define $$x_n = \frac{2}{4\pi n + \pi}\to 0$$
   $$
   f(x_n) = \sin (2\pi n + \pi/2) = 1\neq f(0)
   $$
   so $f$ is not continous in 0.
2. Let $r>0$, $\delta = r$.
   $$
   |x|<\delta\Rightarrow |g(x)|\leq |x| <r
   $$so $g$ is continous in 0.